# Count the number of times keywords (in a table) appear in a field in another table

Tags: mysql

I will simplify my problem in order to explain it.

I have a table which contains text messages posted by users and another table which contains keywords.

- I want to display, for each user, the number of times keywords are found in text messages.
- I don't want the result to display a keyword if it's not found in text messages.
- I wan't it to be case INSENSITIVE. All keywords are lowered but in messages, you can find lower & upper chars.

Because I'm not sure that my explanation is clear enough, here comes the SQLFiddle.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c402a

Hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for. It wasn't easy for me but here is my query :

```
 SELECT t_msg.msg_usr, 
        t_list.list_word, 
        count(t_list.list_word),       
        t_msg.msg_text       
 FROM t_msg
 INNER JOIN t_list
 ON LOWER(t_msg.msg_text) LIKE CONCAT("%", t_list.list_word, "%")
 GROUP BY t_msg.msg_usr, t_list.list_word;
```

The SQLFiddle is there : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba052/8

Comment: But that's incorrect .It's showing `count` of 2 for keyword `here` even though `here` has been  mentioned only once in table 1 i.e `I am here`.

Comment: What you're saying is correct but "here" appears twice because of "there". This display the number of times the KEYWORD "here" is found not the number of times the WORD "here" is found. I guess if I wan't this I should use : LIKE CONCAT("% ", t_list.list_word, " %") ... with spaces ... but I doesn't output the correct answer (because the keywords can't be surrounded by special chars or none ... not a space). So do you have a solution ?

Comment: I checked your fiddle..and i found nothing wrong in it??So what more are you expecting?

Comment: Yeah I expect something more in order to solve the problem you told me about. My query will output the number of times "here" appears in the messages. But as you said, "there" will be counted. I don't wan't "there" to be counted. In other words : I wan't it to counted only if the full word is found. If I use the spaces in "% " it won't be correct for this kind of message : "I will be here." because "here" is not followed by a space. Am I clear enough ? Sorry I am not

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation would be to not try solving this with a query. It's possible to write a query that will do it, such query will scan the messages table for each keyword separately, and produce a count (or a row that you can group by), but this won't scale, or be reliable in sense of language search.

Here is what you might want to do:

1. Create a table to map (user_id, keyword_id) to a count of this keyword in messages of this user. Let's call it t_keyword_count.
2. Each time you receive a message, before you save the message into the database, search it for all the keywords you care about (using whatever good text search libraries that account for misspellings, etc.). You should know the (user_id) for this message.
3. You will, at that point, be ready to add the message to the database, and will have an array of (keyword_id) with keywords that this message will have.
4. In a transaction, insert the message into the t_msg table, and run update/insert for (user_id,keyword_id) to have value=value+1 (or +n, if you need to count the same keyword more than once in the same message) for the t_keyword_count table.

If you are trying to solve the problem of having to do the above on existing data, you can do this manually, just to build up that t_keyword_count table first (depends on how many keywords you have in total, but even if there are a lot, this can be scripted). But you should change (or mirror) the t_msg.msg_text field to be a field suitable for text search, and use SQL text search functionality to find the keywords.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and all your advices. I have to run this script one in a month or once in a week. I will probably use CRON. I understood what you wrote and I will keep it in my mind if I got problems with my solution(scalability). But your idea is a good one. Thanks